# Há alguma diferença entre o presente e o futuro do subjuntivo?

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

Existe alguma diferença (semântica ou estilo/registo) entre o presente e o futuro do conjuntivo?

Geralmente, dada construção ou leva o tempo presente ou o futuro, e pode  corresponder a um estado presente ou futuro:

> *Se ele estiver em casa, hei de visitá-lo.* (futuro, = se ele estiver então em casa/se ele vier a estar em casa/se ele houver de estar em casa)
>   *Se ele estiver em casa, vou visitá-lo.* (presente, = se ele estiver agora em casa; a primeira impressão de "ir" aqui é um futuro imediato)
>   *Caso ele esteja em casa, hei de visitá-lo.*
>   *Caso ele esteja em casa, vou visitá-lo.*

O tempo verbal não me parece fazer diferença -- a primeira é equivalente à terceira e a segunda à quarta. Mas se detetarmos uma diferença, pode sempre contrargumentar-se que a diferença está na construção e não no tempo verbal.

Por isso, talvez mais interessantes são os casos em que se pode usar quer o presente, quer o futuro do subjuntivo:

> *Abre-lhe a porta assim que ele chegar.*
>   *Abre-lhe a porta assim que ele chegue.*

A primeira parece-me mais comum, mas de resto também não creio que haja qualquer diferença.

(A questão também se poderia aplicar aos tempos compostos (tiver/houver chegado vs tenha/haja chegado), mas deixemos isso para outra altura.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posso responder com algumas impressões pessoais. Para mim, falante de português brasileiro, as quatro primeiras frases de fato soam equivalentes. Nesses casos, talvez possa se argumentar que a escolha entre uma ou outra forma seja de fato mais uma questão puramente estilística do que semântica, assim como podemos escolher entre o subjuntivo e o infinitivo pessoal em certos casos:

> Ele fez o pão para que o comamos.
>
> Ele fez o pão para nós comermos.

A sexta frase:

> Abre-lhe a porta assim que ele chegue.

Soa-me bem estranha na escolha do presente do subjuntivo; para meu ouvido, apenas o futuro caberia aí. Mas isso poderia também ser apenas um viés meu, e não refletir as impressões de outrem.

Vale lembrar, por outro lado, que algumas construções requerem o futuro do subjuntivo e não podem ser facilmente reformuladas com o presente. Por exemplo,

> Quando ele estiver em casa, hei de visitá-lo.

O "quando" parece para mim comunicar uma noção de futuro por si só, isto é, independentemente do resto da frase. Nesse sentido, ele é bem parecido com a construção "assim que" das últimas duas frases.

Comment: Pelo menos em Portugal, "assim que chegue" é perfeitamente aceitável. No corpus CETEMPúblico a distribuição de tempos para `"assim" "que" [pos="PERS"]{1,2} @[pos="V.*" & temcagr=".*_SUBJ"]` é 31-24-15 para o futuro, presente e imperfeito do subjuntivo, respetivamente, com 6 falsos positivos para o presente (e.g. "basta assim que se faça").

Comment: Uma query melhor é permitir omissão do pronome `[pos="PERS"]{0,2}`. Aí o  resultado é 251-126-66.

Comment: Eu experimentei chutar o presente do conjuntivo lá bem para o futuro, e nem assim me choca: _vou poupar agora para que daqui a dez anos possa viver descansado._ Mas o meu choque ou falta dele pode não ser um bom critério de correção.

Comment: Esta resposta mistura o futuro do subjuntivo com o infinitivo. Eu nunca falei de infinitivo. Sim, pode substituir-se "para que + pr_sub" por "para + infinitivo", mas isso diz-nos nada sobre o contraste presente/futuro do subjuntivo.

Comment: Ademais, o facto de "quando" ou "se" pedirem o futuro do subjuntivo parece-me uma questão meramente formal; podem ser substituídos por "logo/assim que"/"no momento em que" e "caso" e aí o presente do conjuntivo já é possível ou obrigatório, respetivamente.

Comment: @Artefacto eu não quis deixar a entender que a situação do infinitivo servisse para se concluir algo sobre o futuro do subjuntivo. Apenas quis apontar para uma situação análoga com construções verbais diferentes, para lembrar que essas escolhas estilísticas são bem comuns.

Comment: @Artefacto sobre o uso de "logo"/"assim que", devo atribuir minhas conclusões a meu ouvido brasileiro: parece-me que construções como "assim que ele esteja em casa, hei de visitá-lo" soariam estranhas para um falante brasileiro. Talvez o futuro do subjuntivo seja mais distinto do presente no Brasil que em Portugal?

Answer (score 1):

A minha sensibilidade é em todos os exemplos da pergunta igual à do Artefacto. Mas encontrei esta [Ciberdúvida](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/futuro-do-conjuntivo-e-presente-do-conjuntivo-em-oracao-relativa/33264) que talvez justifique a aversão do Arthur a *abre-lhe a porta assim que ele chegue.* 
Por um lado o artigo diz:

> A diferença de interpretação entre presente e futuro do conjuntivo é muito subtil, e a utilização de um ou outro tem mais que ver com a presença de determinadas conjunções: **quando, sempre que, se**, por exemplo, são conjunções que selecionam futuro do conjuntivo, enquanto **caso, embora, ainda que**, entre outras, selecionam o presente

Por outro lado, a diferença subtil parece ser que o futuro do subjuntivo abrange o futuro e presente, enquanto o presente abrange apenas, coisa surpreendente, o presente. Acrescenta no entanto que há pessoas que abrangem o futuro com o presente, e usam um ou outro dos tempos aleatoriamente. Ora na frase:

> Abre-lhe a porta assim que ele chegue

subentende-se que ele chegará no futuro. Logo se usarmos o presente do subjuntivo só para o presente, não o poderíamos usar na frase acima. Agora este argumento invalidaria também a frase:

> Caso ele esteja em casa, hei de visitá-lo.

A menos que se interpretasse *caso ele esteja em casa (agora), hei de visitá-lo (no futuro onde quer que ele venha a estar na altura)*. Mas não é com certeza este o nosso entendimento da frase. Talvez um teste radical da equivalência entre presente e futuro do conjuntivo é colocar a ação  bem no futuro:

> Vou plantar esta cerejeira para que daqui a dez anos **tenhamos** cerejas.

Se aceitarmos esta frase aceitamos a equivalência temporal, e a escolha entre presente e futuro do conjuntivo dependeria apenas da conjunção precedente. A mim, a frase soa-me perfeitamente.